# Deleting a cloned div

Tags: jquery, html, button, clone

```
<div class="transactionsWrapper">
  <input type="button" value="Delete" />
</div>
```

If I cloned the div above let's say 5 times, what's the jquery code to delete the div based on which delete button was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".transactionsWrapper input:button" ).click( function() {
    $( this ).parent().remove();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('input:button[value="Delete"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.transactionsWrapper').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.transactionsWrapper button', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: If jQuery version is lower then 1.7, just need to replace `on` function to `delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("transactionsWrapper")){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just... delete the parent of the input?

```
$('input[value=Delete]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**EDIT**

Well... That won't work if you add cloned `<div>` elements *after* assigning the event listener. The safest way is to use delegation:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input[value=Delete]', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: @Ben Is that a comment about an earlier version of the answer? Because, as it stands, it kind of looks exactly like your answer.

Comment: Yeah, that was about an older version.